# How to replace all list values in every column in a dataframe

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe, which has columns like below:

```
a1 <- c("Hello", "World")
b1 <- c("[1, 2]", "[1,2,3]")
c1 <- c("[1, 2, 3, 3]", "[1, 4, 5, 6]")
d1 <- c("[]", "[1]")


data <- data.frame(a1, b1, c1, d1)
```

I want to replace all the columns which have list values with its the length of the list instead. I tried using some apply functions, but could not get it to work.

Comment: That is not valid R code...

Comment: Stupid mistake, lol. Corrected it.

Comment: Still not a valid R code. Did you run this code and check?

Comment: My bad, ran and checked it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
a1 <- c("Hello", "World")
b1 <- c("[1, 2]", "[1,2,3]")
c1 <- c("[1, 2, 3, 3]", "[1, 4, 5, 6]")
d1 <- c("[]", "[1]")
data <- data.frame(a1, b1, c1, d1, stringsAsFactors = F)

data <- data.frame(apply(data,2,function(x) gsub(pattern = "\\[", "", x)), stringsAsFactors = F)
data <- data.frame(apply(data,2,function(x) gsub(pattern = "\\]", "", x)), stringsAsFactors = F)

data$b1 <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(data$b1, ","), length))
data$c1 <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(data$c1, ","), length))
data$d1 <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(data$d1, ","), length))

data

     a1 b1 c1 d1
1 Hello  2  4  0
2 World  3  4  1
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried recreating the scenario I have with a sample code, but forgot the case where the list's length was either 0 or 1. I have updated my sample code.